# problem with Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip'

Tags: php, apache, php-ziparchive

I´m trying to update my composer in my proyect and command return this message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_zip.dll' (tried: C:/xampp/php/ext/php_zip.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado), C:/xampp/php/ext/php_php_zip.dll.dll (No se puede encontrar el m├│dulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
```

in my `php.ini` i uncomment `extension=zip` and i add this dll: `extension=php_zip.dll`

i donloaded this package: `php_zip-1.12.4-5.6-ts-vc11-x64` and `php_zip.dll` i move it into `C:\xampp\php\ext`

i don´t know what i´m doing wrong, but when i do `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` return this message...

I hope that anybody can help me.

sorry for my bad english and rewards

Comment: I have no clue where you've got that file from, but it seems to be listed on https://windows.php.net/Downloads/pecl/releases/zip/1.12.4/ as a release from 2014. I doubt that this is still compatible with current versions of PHP

Comment: @NicoHaase yes i think that it´s my problem... but now how i can add this extension?

Comment: That depends on what PHP version you use, and where you've downloaded it from